# New declared variables and properties not recognized by VS2012

Tags: asp.net

I declared some variables in the functions of controller class, and the properties in model calss. New Declared variables and Properties are not working in my asp.net mvc project.
But I am not getting any error. I cleaned the solutions and projects individually and build each of them, but still the variables and properties not working. I do addwatch on debug mode, getting the error "The name xxx does not exists in the current context".

But the variables are previously declared in the controller class working fine and showing value in debug mode also.Some days before I got this kind of problem in some other project, there I tried to clean and build the solution and that time it worked. That was compilation problem. But now I cannot understand why this project behaves abnormally.

Comment: Where did you declare your properties? How are you using them? Are you trying to use them in Views? What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: I declared some variables in the functions of controller class, and the properties in model calss. I have no error in my project build. So I clean the project and solution and build them all... But problem is same ...the code I am trying ....